# How to send OFFLINE String or Integer data to Arduino using ESP8226 wifi Module?

Tags: android, arduino

please someone one help me, is that possible to send Offline [string,integer] commands from android to Arduino using ESP8226 module?
like chat with WIFI direct without using any modem.

if it is possible can you give me a link about how to do it?
I'm new to Arduino and i dont know what should i look for.

**EDIT:**

this is my module picture

[module picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N066G.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the how to program module with Arduino and problem resolved.

```
VCC=3.3V

Arduino          ESP8266

Rx      ---->    Rx
Tx      ---->    Tx
VCC     <----    VCC
GND     <----    GND
////////////////////////////////////
Arduino
RESET -----> GND
////////////////////////////////////
ESP8266

EN ---->   VCC+(270ohm Resistor) // just in case of high voltage
IO0 ---->  GND
```

in the IDE's Board Manager select Generic ESP8266 Module then Upload your Sketch.

**Notice:** Remove EN AND IO0 pins after programming,if you dont do that when you connect power of board all data will be removed and you should program it again.

Thanks for @Martin for His Help and the link of library

Answer (score 0):

ESP8266 can run as an Access Point, that way you can connect to from Android([example](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/esp8266-thing-hookup-guide/example-sketch-ap-web-server)).
Then you can send commands from ESP to the Arduino over serial the same, as you would from a PC.

EDIT:
If you controlling ESP by AT commands, there are some tutorials:

[configure access point](https://dominicm.com/esp8266-configure-access-point/)

[AP with WifiBee](https://techtutorialsx.com/2017/05/20/esp8266-wifi-bee-setting-an-access-point-with-at-commands/) (* WifiBee is just an PCB with ESP8266 on it)

Sumary:

> ## Set SSID, password, channel and encryption.
>
> AT+CWSAP="ESP8266","123",3,0
>
> ## Set the IP address of the Access Point.
>
> AT+CIPAP="192.168.0.101"
>
> ## Enable DHCP for AP mode.
>
> AT+CWDHCP=0,0

After that:

> ## Configure TCP Server.
>
> AT+CIPSERVER=1,1234
>
> ## Set connection mode.
>
> AT+CIPMUX=1
>
> ... ...

[Basic description of ESP + AT commands on wiki](https://www.itead.cc/wiki/ESP8266_Serial_WIFI_Module)

[Complete documentation of AT commands is here](http://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/4a-esp8266_at_instruction_set_en.pdf)

Comment: i tried the link you gave but i get errors on Compiling. no such a file or directory to <functional>
no errors in file that included <functional> but only get error on compiling

Comment: Ok, I guess you have the ESP connected to arduino that is controlling it by AT commands and the example I sent deals with programming ESP directly. I will edit the answer and add some examples of setting up AP by AT commands

Comment: thanks for commands but the dont work and dont return Ok after sending. or maybe i dont know how to send. i use software serial to send commands is that right?
like this:    
SoftwareSerial wifi() and wifi.println("AT") nothing returns with wifi.read()

Comment: do i need another board to use this library? because it says use board manager and select generic esp8266 module , not arduino uno or else.

Comment: You should not need any library to issue AT commands to the ESP via serial, actually, if you have an USB-TTL-serial adapter, you can just connect it directly to your PC and try issuing AT commands from Arduino IDEs Serial Monitor.

What baudrate are you using on the software serial? Possibly you should try it with HW serial first, to make it more simple.

Did you get the comunication with ESP working in some other way before?

I have the ESP-01 module somewhere, it has been some since I was using it. When I get home, I will try it out and send you some acutal code.